# Is there a maximum length of integers I can enter for C?

Tags: c

for the b/m, I am trying to sum up the digits of an integer. eg. if I enter 1234, i get the answer 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

this works for integers up to 10 digits long. after that, if i enter an integer with 11 digits like 12345678912, it returns me a negative answer.

Could anyone help to explain why this is so please? And if there's anyway I can get around it?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number, single_digit, sum;

    printf("What number would you like to sum:\n");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    sum = 0;
    while(number != 0)
    {
        single_digit = number % 10;
        sum += single_digit;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    printf("The sum of the number is %i.\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integer overflow is in action!

Comment: I am actually surprised it works for ten digit numbers, that is quite more than the usual 32767 I would expect

Comment: @LorenzoBoccaccia that's a short's limit.

Comment: In C, int data type value range is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If you enter 11 digits, it overflows.

Comment: really? on all platforms?

Comment: @mizanurahma: Not always. That is the range for a signed 32-bit integer. 32-bit is the standard for int, but the C standard doesn't mandate anything. It could be 16, it could be 64. Not usually necessary to know, just good to have in mind.

Comment: @mizanurahma C _specifies_ that the _minimum_ range of an `int` is -32767 to +32767.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum limit for an `int` is `INT_MAX`. You are getting -ve value because `12345678912` doesn't fit in the range of `int` and causes integer overflow.

Better to change your `main`'s body to

```
sum = 0;
int ch;
printf("Enter the number would you like to sum:\n");
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
{
    sum += ch - '0';
}
printf("The sum of the number is %i.\n", sum);
```

Since `getchar` reads single character at a time, you will get your desired output by adding these to `sum`.

Comment: This may be a solution to the problem, but it's almost certainly not an answer to the question

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't it be `sum += (ch - '0');`?

Comment: @Useless; Oops! I was in hurry :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the maximum value an integer can hold is `INT_MAX` (whose value depends on your platform).

An `unsigned int` can hold larger (positive) numbers, up to `UINT_MAX`.

You may be able to fit more in `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` - again, the details are platform-specific. After that, you're looking for a bignum library.

---

NB. since you just want to sum the *digits*, using something like haccks' approach is much simpler, and less likely to overflow. It's still possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because an int is only 4 bytes. What that means is any number larger than 2^31 will cause the buffer to overflow. A more detailed explanation can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow. If you want to get around it, use an unsigned int instead, it will let you go up to 2^32 instead, but it will not let you have any negative numbers.

Comment: Well, no. An `int` is the machine word size. A `long`, on the other hand, is defined to be a _minimum_ of 4 bytes. So, if he's on a 32-bit system, you're almost right.

Answer (score 0):

The `int` type is (usually) a signed 32-bit integer (you can see your size by printing `sizeof(int)*8` to get the number of bits.

This means that the maximum value you can store in an int is 2^32 - 1, but, because `int` is signed, the range is actually half that.

Answer (score 0):

In C a specific type of integer is stored in a fixed amount of memory. On all current architectures an `int` is stored in 32 bits. Since `int` carries a sign, the most significant bit is assigned to the sign. This means that the biggest integer you can store in an `int` is `2^31 - 1`. You are seeing a negative number because the your int is overflowing into the sign bit and making it negative.

Comment: Disagree with "On all current architectures an int is stored in 32 bits".  _Billions_ of embedded processors are made annually.  Even in 2014, a large chunk of these (if not most), use 16-bit `int`.  C is _very popular_ on these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Number types in c are limited. You can find the max ints in limits.h

You should read the input as a string (char array) and process each character to allow arbitrary* lenght numbers.

*The sum still need to be less than max int. the input string must be big enough to contain what the user writes

Answer (score 0):

An integer with 11 digits like 12345678912 if too large to fit in `number` which is an `int` on your platform.

In C, an `int` has of range of *at least* -32767 to 32767.  On your platform it apparently has the range -2147483648 to +2147483647.

If code is to read the entire integer at once, the maximum number of digits is limited by the range of the various available integer types.

C provides an integer type called `intmax_t` and its unsigned partner `uintmax_t` which typically has the maximum range available on a given platform.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void MaximalSumOFDigits(void) {
  uintmax_t number;
  double widthf = log10(UINTMAX_MAX);
  int widthi = ((int) floor(widthf)) - 1;
  char buf[widthi + 2];

  printf("What number would you like to sum: (up to %d digits)\n", widthi);
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  number = strtoumax(buf, &endptr, 10);
  if (*endptr != '\n')
    Handle_UnexpectedInput();
  if (errno) // This should not easily happen as buffer has limited length
    Handle_TooBigANumber();

  int sum = 0;
  while (number > 0) {  // avoiding ASCII dependence
    sum += number % 10;
    number /= 10;
  }
  printf("The sum of the number is %d.\n", sum);
}
```

With a 64-bit `uintmax_t`, allows numbers up to
18446744073709551615 (any 19 digit number and some 20 digit numbers)

The above suggests to the user input limit of limit of
_9999999999999999999 (any 19 digit number)